# How to apply a clicked command to a panel menu to expand in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using primefaces library and implemented their panel menu component. I want to expand the panel menu items on a button click. I have tried the following implementation.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PanelMenu } from 'primereact/panelmenu';
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';
    
class PanelMenu0 extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    this.selectedItemNew = this.selectedItemNew.bind(this);
  }

  this.items = 
  [
    {
        label: 'New',
        icon: 'pi pi-plus',
        command: (event) => {
          this.selectedItemNew = event.originalEvent.currentTarget;
        }
    }
  ];
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Button onClick={this.selectedItemMenu.click()}>
        <PanelMenu model={this.items}  />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But this does not seem to working out, I  even tried binding it to the `Button onClick event`. Where am I going wrong ?

EDIT::
I am getting the following error.
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` for the line in constructor.

Comment: onClick={this.selectedItemMenu.click} - Basically you have to pass the function to `onClick` event

Comment: And also could you please add some more info including the imports

Comment: @UKS It does not work. I am getting the `undefined` error

Comment: please add code sandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-menu-expand-on-button-click-m2plu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It says `DependencyNotFound` despite adding it. Using code sandbox for the first time, please ignore if you see something stupid @UKS

Comment: updated the sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-menu-expand-on-button-click-forked-k45e9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: what is the issue here ?

Comment: On the button click, I want one of the menu items to expand, have a look at this [link](https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/panelmenu) .. If I click on the created button, I want the file menu to expand.

Comment: You can refer my sandbox its updated with the dependencies. @UKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below approach,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { PanelMenu } from "primereact/panelmenu";
import { Button } from "primereact/button";

export default class App extends Component {
  items = [
    {
      className: "file1", //Define classname for item
      label: "File",
      icon: "pi pi-fw pi-file",
      items: [
        {
          label: "New",
          icon: "pi pi-fw pi-plus",
          items: [
            {
              label: "Bookmark",
              icon: "pi pi-fw pi-bookmark"
            },
            {
              label: "Video",
              icon: "pi pi-fw pi-video"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          label: "Delete",
          icon: "pi pi-fw pi-trash"
        },
        {
          label: "Export",
          icon: "pi pi-fw pi-external-link"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Edit",
      icon: "pi pi-fw pi-pencil",
      items: [
        {
          label: "Left",
          icon: "pi pi-fw pi-align-left"
        },
        {
          label: "Right",
          icon: "pi pi-fw pi-align-right"
        },
        {
          label: "Center",
          icon: "pi pi-fw pi-align-center"
        },
        {
          label: "Justify",
          icon: "pi pi-fw pi-align-justify"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Users",
      icon: "pi pi-fw pi-user",
      items: [
        {
          label: "New",
          icon: "pi pi-fw pi-user-plus"
        },
        {
          label: "Delete",
          icon: "pi pi-fw pi-user-minus"
        },
        {
          label: "Search",
          icon: "pi pi-fw pi-users",
          items: [
            {
              label: "Filter",
              icon: "pi pi-fw pi-filter",
              items: [
                {
                  label: "Print",
                  icon: "pi pi-fw pi-print"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              icon: "pi pi-fw pi-bars",
              label: "List"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Events",
      icon: "pi pi-fw pi-calendar",
      items: [
        {
          label: "Edit",
          icon: "pi pi-fw pi-pencil",
          items: [
            {
              label: "Save",
              icon: "pi pi-fw pi-calendar-plus"
            },
            {
              label: "Delete",
              icon: "pi pi-fw pi-calendar-minus"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          label: "Archieve",
          icon: "pi pi-fw pi-calendar-times",
          items: [
            {
              label: "Remove",
              icon: "pi pi-fw pi-calendar-minus"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  handleClick = () => {
    document.querySelector(".file1 a").click();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click here</button>
        <PanelMenu model={this.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-menu-expand-on-button-click-forked-i2084?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This is the normal `primefaces` code that we can implement .. I want an additional setting where I can `use separate buttons for expanding the menu items` (normal expand of menu items on click shall continue the same) .. Say an extra `File` button which when clicked will expand the FIle menu items list.

Comment: I have updated the codebase. Please let me know if anything I need to include there.

Comment: Excellent.!! Exactly what I wanted. I would appreciate if you could please update the same in your answer so I could accept it :)